# How do I set the maximum line length in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

I am using PyCharm on Windows and want to change the settings to limit the maximum line length to `79` characters, as opposed to the default limit of `120` characters.

Where can I change the maximum amount of characters per line in PyCharm?

Answer (score 597, accepted):

Here is screenshot of my Pycharm. Required settings is in following path: `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> General: Right margin (columns)`

[image: Pycharm 4 Settings Screenshot]

Comment: I am wondering why the default value is set to 120 characters. PEP 8 clearly states: [Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

Comment: @Krøllebølle PEP 8 is just a recomentation, not a mandatory requirement.

Comment: Indeed, and in retrospect for the project where we followed PEP 8, we were way too strict. Following the 79 line limitation, the code quickly becomes unreadable and unmaintainable. Let's quote [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds): `A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is most important. But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply.`

Comment: @Krøllebølle. I believe (without any evidence) that the tight restriction in PEP8 was intended for the code Python code-base so that it's workable in the most restrictive environments: those doing coding with 80 column terminals. Those writing libraries and programs in more sophisticated environments would find 80 columns to do more damage than good.

Comment: PEP8 E501 — line too long (> 79 characters) — is way deprecated nowadays. Even big and well know projects like Django don't use it anymore (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23395), as you can see here: `One big exception to PEP 8 is our preference of longer line lengths. We’re well into the 21st Century, and we have high-resolution computer screens that can fit way more than 79 characters on a screen. Don’t limit lines of code to 79 characters if it means the code looks significantly uglier or is harder to read.`

Comment: @ChrisCogdon I have an argument to counter the "ancient terminals" strawman(?) from Django: On my 1920px wide screen I can fit 3 source files that has a max width ~79 columns horizontally. I believe that it provides me a better overview of what I'm working with as I can have the library module as well as the template file open right next to the view I'm working on.

Comment: +1 @joar and I have one further point; once you decide 120 characters is OK, suddenly people find that too restrictive too :P I myself have adopted a "soft 79" rule in some of my projects; I aim for 79, but don' worry if lines here and there go slightly over.

Comment: @joar is right - the reason for the limitation is not old monitors, but readability and being able to show files next to each other (think of diffs or three-way-merges). Having said this, 79 is probably really too small. The "black" formatter uses 88 as default with the explanation that this "... happens to be 10% over 80. This number was found to produce significantly shorter files than sticking with 80 (the most popular), or even 79 (used by the standard library). In general, 90-ish seems like the wise choice." In practice, I found that maximum line sizes around 90 also worked best for me.

Answer (score 83):

For PyCharm 2018.1 on Mac:

Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>), then `Editor -> Code Style`:

[image]

For PyCharm 2018.3 on Windows:

File -> Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), then `Editor -> Code Style`:

To follow PEP-8 set `Hard wrap at` to 80.

Answer (score 25):

For **PyCharm 4**

File >> Settings >> Editor >> Code Style: Right margin (columns)

**suggestion:** Take a look at other options in that tab, they're very helpful

Answer (score 8):

For anyone, or myself if I reload my machine, who this is not working for when you do a code reformat there is an additional option to check under editor->code style->python : ensure right margin is not exceeded.  Once this was selected the reformat would work.

[image: preference_highlighted]

Answer (score 8):

For PyCharm 2021.x this did the trick for python:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can even set a separate **right margin** for HTML. Under the specified path:

File >> Settings >> Editor >> Code Style >> HTML >> Other Tab >> Right margin (columns)

This is very useful because generally HTML and JS may be usually long in one line than Python. :)

Comment: I was looking for this. Thanks @andy, but even increasing right margin for HTML, the text continues wrapping in the 79th column. Is there some setting more?

Comment: Same here, any idea how to make this work? just html stops afterwards?

Answer (score 4):

For PyCharm 2019.3.1,  I see this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For PyCharm 2017

We can follow below:
File >> Settings >> Editor >> Code Style.

Then provide values for `Hard Wrap` & `Visual Guides`
`for wrapping` while typing, tick the checkbox.

NB: look at other tabs as well, viz. Python, HTML, JSON etc.