# PyCharm: Reformat code breaks django template

Tags: django-templates, pycharm

If I run "reformat code" PyCharm changes this line:

```
    {% ajax_dialog_opener url=duplicate_url|add:'?hide_messages=true' reload_on_success=False label='FoooBaar' dialog_title='Foo foo baaar' type='link'
```

After reformat code:

```
    {% ajax_dialog_opener url=duplicate_url|add:'?hide_messages=true' reload_on_success=False label='FoooBaar' dialog_title='Foo foo baaar' type='link'
    data_shortcut="mod+d" %}
```

But this means the new code is broken.

Is there a way to stop PyCharm from breaking above line?

Version: PyCharm community 2018.2

Comment: Is there anything missing in the first code snippet you have send? I can't find the what is the issue with both the snippets.

Comment: @ArunT PyCharm inserts a new-line character. This breaks it. Maybe django templates are different then pure Jinja.  I don't know.

Comment: Hello @guettli, isn't that worked for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the maximum line length in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319422/how-do-i-set-the-maximum-line-length-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 8):

Go to

Preferences > Editor > Code Style

Change "Hard Wrap At" value to something bigger like 1000 (max).

Comment: This makes the issue less likely, but it still could happen. But this is a valid work-around

Comment: no it is not a work around, intellij gets the "cutting line" of the long lines by this setting.

Comment: and what happens to lines longer than 200 chars?

Comment: well, make it 500, 1000... you don't have to set it exactly 200.