# How do I set the maximum line length in PyCharms python Console?

Tags: python, pycharm

Currently my Python pyCharm console would return:

```
Out[74]: 
   GroupID      qdate CUSIP8  FundID  Identified  Identified2  NetChange  \
0        1 2009-03-01      b     4.5           0            3        0.0   
   IdNew  
0      0
```

**I want to increase the number of characters before pyCharms python console automatically breaks the line.** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319422/how-do-i-set-the-maximum-line-length-in-pycharm) seems to suggest changing the settings in the `Code Style` tab, but it does not work for me. Maybe because the other questions refers to an older version of Pycharm. Any ideas how to fix it?

[image: My PyCharm config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably pandas doing that by default.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203929730-How-to-see-more-than-five-columns-of-a-data-frame-output-in-PyCharm-run-window